# Accordion Material UI Component Removes Styling From NavBar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

So, I am currently working on a project with Material UI, React, Etc. and I have encountered a bizarre issue that is making my head spin.

I have a Material UI Side-Bar on a page in my project. Inside of that side-bar I am using tabs to display accordions with unique information inside of them. When I place my accordion inside of these tabs, it over-writes the header styling completely (loss of color) and the menu loses its verticality. To showcase, I will be posting the code and also issue below.

**THINGS I HAVE TRIED:**

1. Adjust the tabs CSS options.
2. Adjust my global theme inside of the bars
3. Removing the tabs, and reorganizing them.

Please if you can help me I'd be super grateful, tried so many things via google, youtube etc can't find issue to my problem. Thank you!!

***THIS IS WHAT IMAGE NAV BAR IS SUPPOSED TO LOOK LIKE***
[image: THIS IS WHAT IMAGE NAV BAR IS SUPPOSED TO LOOK LIKE]

***THIS IS WHAT HAPPENS AFTER I ADD IN ACCORDION***

[image]

***SIDE BAR CODE:***

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Drawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import SimpleAccordion from "./Accordion";

const drawerWidth = 240;


function TabPanel(props) {
    const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

    return (
        <div>
            {value === index && (
                <Box p={3} color="primary">
                    <Typography>{children}</Typography>
                </Box>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

function a11yProps(index) {
    return {
        id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
        'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
    };
}

function PermanentDrawerLeft() {

    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    };

    const drawer = (
        <div>
            <Toolbar sx={{
                pt: 10,
            }}>
            <Divider />
                <Tabs  orientation="vertical" variant="scrollable" value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs">
                    <Tab label="Freshman" {...a11yProps(0)} />
                    <Tab label="Sophomore" {...a11yProps(1)} />
                    <Tab label="Junior" {...a11yProps(2)} />
                    <Tab label="Senior" {...a11yProps(3)} />
                </Tabs>
            </Toolbar>
        </div>
    );

    /*      Working on it?
             <CssBaseline />
            <ResponsiveAppBar/>
            <TipsNavBar/>
     */

    return (
        <div>

        <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            <Drawer
                sx={{
                    width: drawerWidth,
                    flexShrink: 0,
                    pt: 10,
                }}
                variant="permanent"
                anchor="left"
            >
                <Divider />
                {drawer}
            </Drawer>
            <Box
                sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
            >
                <Toolbar />

                <div>
                <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
                    <SimpleAccordion schoolYear = "freshman"/>
                </TabPanel>
                <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
                    <SimpleAccordion schoolYear = "sophomore"/>
                </TabPanel>
                <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
                    <SimpleAccordion schoolYear = "junior"/>
                </TabPanel>
                <TabPanel value={value} index={3}>
                    <SimpleAccordion schoolYear = "senior"/>
                </TabPanel>
                </div>
            </Box>
        </Box>
</div>
    );
}
```

***NAV BAR CODE:***

```
import * as React from "react";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import { purple } from "@mui/material/colors";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";



// import { View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import logo from "../assests/logo.png";
import ARC from "../assests/ARC.png";
import csilogo from "../assests/csilogo.png";
import tips from "../assests/lightbulb.png";
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import Menu_icon from '../assests/menu_icon.png'
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import '../pages/Home';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import TipsNavBar from "./TipsNavbar";
// import PopupState from '@mui/material/Popover'

function ResponsiveAppBar() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} className="AppBar">
      <AppBar position="fixed" color="primary" sx={{ zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1 }} >
        <Toolbar>
      
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            {/* <Image
        style={styles.tinyLogo}
        source={{
          uri:"https://res.cloudinary.com/andreahabib/image/upload/v1643912027/ARC_b6azyw.svg",
        }}
      /> */}
            <img alt="arc logo" src={logo} height="60px" width="60px" />
            <img
              alt="academic resource centre"
              src={ARC}
              height="50px"
              width="110px"
            />
          </Typography>

          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            component="div"
            align="right"
            sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
          >
            <img
              alt="college of staten island logo"
              src={csilogo}
              height="50px"
              width="250px"
            />
          </Typography>
          <Button
        id="basic-button"
        aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu' : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
        ml={30}
        onClick={handleClick}
        startIcon={<Avatar src={Menu_icon} />}

      >
  
      </Button>
     
      <Menu
        id="basic-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        MenuListProps={{
          'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem component ={Link} to= "/">Home</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Career</MenuItem>
        
      </Menu>
    
        </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default ResponsiveAppBar;
```

**ACCORDION CODE:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Accordion from '@material-ui/core/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';



function SimpleAccordion(schoolYear) {
    const name = {...schoolYear};

    const years = {
        freshman: ["Freshman Milestones fake text", " Freshman todo fake text", " Freshman Summer fake text"],
        sophomore: [" Sophomore Milestones fake text", " Sophomore todo fake text", " Sophomore Summer fake text"],
        junior: ["Junior Milestones fake text", " Junior todo fake text", " Junior Summer fake text"],
        senior: ["Senior Milestones fake text", "Senior todo fake text", " Senior Summer fake text"],
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Accordion color="primary">
                <AccordionSummary
                    aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                    id="panel1a-header"
                >
                    <Typography>Milestones</Typography>
                </AccordionSummary>
                <AccordionDetails>
                    <Typography>
                        {years[name.schoolYear][0]}
                    </Typography>
                </AccordionDetails>
            </Accordion>
            <Accordion>
                <AccordionSummary
                    aria-controls="panel2a-content"
                    id="panel2a-header"
                >
                    <Typography>Todo</Typography>
                </AccordionSummary>
                <AccordionDetails>
                    <Typography>
                        {years[name.schoolYear][1]}
                    </Typography>
                </AccordionDetails>
            </Accordion>
            <Accordion>
                <AccordionSummary
                    aria-controls="panel3a-content"
                    id="panel3a-header"
                >
                    <Typography>Summer</Typography>
                </AccordionSummary>
                <AccordionDetails>
                    {years[name.schoolYear][2]}
                </AccordionDetails>
            </Accordion>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SimpleAccordion;
```

Comment: I don't see where any custom styling/CSS is used. Could you include any CSS of yours that is used over the default component stylings from Material-UI? Could you try also creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Sure! Will update accordingly, Also by custom styling I meant I am using the in built MUI theme provider and created my own theme, my "primary" is the color in first picture.

Comment: Thanks. With a live version then we can at least inspect the computed styles in the browser's dev tools and see what is overriding rules or winning the CSS selector specificity battle.

Comment: I'm having almost the exact same issue - did you figure out what the cause was?